# Weird bug on Firefox displaying overlay in image

Tags: html, css

When opening this website https://www.sitepor500...com.br (please replace the 3 dots with just one so this link does not get any SEO juice as many of you may complain) you can see there is an image as background and an overlay of a specific pattern on top of the images at the background.

On Chrome everything works fine, however on FF I see strange patterns on the screen, like the image attached. I have my zoom set to 100% (I know using zoom different than 100% may cause this problem in any other browser because of moirè effect) and everything else on the FF is in the defaults.

So I ask you, is there any CSS property that I can set to the overlay so Firefox renders it right?

I realized this bug only happens when my WINDOWS is at 125% scale (which is the only recommended option). See the image:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't repeat your issue on the 100% scaled screen. But maybe you should add `background-size: 1px 2px;` to those background image in `#slideshow_fundo1`

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background:url(imagens/vegas-04.png) top left repeat; background-attachment:fixed; background-size: 1px 2px;"></div>
```

This will fix the size of `background-image` to it's native size and prevent those scale issues.

---

**UPDATED**

In your Windows Display settings, set your *Scale and layout* to 100%. Worked for me. Tested your issue on FF with 125% - recreated your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! I did what you said, adding "background-size: 1px 2px;" to the element #slideshow_fundo1 but didnt fix the problem :(

Comment: It could be that resolution of your OS is different of physical native resolution of the monitor?

Comment: Maybe try to set 125% to 100% from your screenshot? i have 100% now on my PC

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Just tested with 125% and had the exact your issue. Added it to an answer.

Comment: Yeap, 125% is the curlprit BUT this is very common on notebooks sold in brazil, they usually offer a 1920x1280 resolution (pretty common) and it's terrible to use like that on windows. Everyone has to end up using 125%, recommended by windows itself. The strange thing is that only FF shows this problem, Chrome and Edge does not.

Answer (score 0):

this happens in firefox on windows machines when scale and layout are set to 125%. If you press ctrl shift -  twice and go back to 80% in firefox it is ok. But that is rediculous.

This is not related to notebooks (in brasil) only. This happens in any windows machine using scale layout 125% on any screen size. I believe FF should fix this problem. You can use any other browser and it does not happen.

Did you report this to firefox?